# svn update fails to get all changes after error

Tags: svn

I am having an issue with svn up not getting all changes. I execute either svn up or svn switch and it encounters the following error "an unversioned file of the same name already exists". I then rename or delete the file from my working copy and execute svn up but it only fetches the files related to the error and nothing else. I execute svn up again to see if it will get more files but it doesn't. To fix the problem I usually have to execute svn switch to a different version and then switch back. What is the correct way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

svn cleanup may help in these cases.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: i think it does. if you don't, please explain why not.